# Azure ADF - how to proceed with pipeline activities only after new files arrival?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have written generic datafiles arrival checking routine using databricks notebooks which accepts filenames and time which specifies acceptable freshness of files. many pipeline uses this notebook and passes filenames tuples and at end notebook returns True or False, to indicate if next workflow activity could start or not. so far so good.
now my question is how to use this in Azure ADF pipeline such that if it fails it should wait for 30 minutes or so and check again by running above notebook again?
this notebook shall run first so that if new files are already there then it should not wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are talking about the notebook activity , you can add a wait activity "on failue  " and set the time for the wait . after wait add a executepipelien actvity . This execute pipeline should point to a pipeline with a execute pipeline ( again ) pointing to the main pipeline which has the notebook activity . Basically this is just a cycle , but will only execute when you have a failure .

Comment: Thanks. looks correct. I could try this and let you know

Comment: I created new pipeline PL_123, added notebook first then on failure wait and then Execute Pipeline. now in settngs for Execute Pipeline the PL_123 does not show up. did I miss something?

Comment: I could always copy this to PL_1234 and execute it from PL_123 and do the same from PL_1234. were you suggesting something like that?

Comment: as an alternative, I am also trying  pipeline with only Until activiity and inside it Notebook and Wait expecting Until to continue looping till Notebook is successful

Comment: I was suggesting the 1234 idea and i think youc an also try out the untill activity .